# Installing Pillow on Max OS Yosemite for Python

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I have very little information on what Pillow is or does, but I have to download it for a class. I use a mac and am following these instructions
http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#os-x-installation

I downloaded Homebrew and now attempt to run the statement it tells me to in my terminal prompt which is

```
$ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
```

but I get an error that reads

"-bash: brew: command not found"

I checked and it says Homebrew is installed so I'm at a loss.

Comment: The second link tells you exactly what to do. What is going wrong when you try that?

Comment: I did the first step and installed Homebrew, but if I enter the other two commands into the terminal prompt it says `-bash: brew: command not found` or `-bash: pip: command not found` @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second link does tell you exactly how to install the module using Homebrew. All you need to do is enter the commands into a terminal.

If you don't have Homebrew, enter the following into a terminal prompt:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then you can enter the following two commands to install Pillow. Have fun! :)

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't understand where to input these things I was trying different things and didn't realize I needed to do a terminal prompt. Now I get it. Thank you

Comment: No worries, sometimes it helps to ask when you are unsure. You're welcome! Have fun :)

Comment: Okay so it's still not working. I did the first step and installed Homebrew, but if I enter the other two commands into the terminal prompt it says `-bash: brew: command not found` or `-bash: pip: command not found` @scorreia

Comment: @Michelle, if you are getting an error that `-bash: brew: command not found` then it's possible that `Homebrew` was not correctly installed. I ran the exact same command on my machine and it works without a problem. If you need any help, please refer to the `Homebrew` website: http://brew.sh/